# What does the 'period' character (.) mean if used in the middle of a PHP string?

Tags: php, string, character, period

Here is some example code:

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

What does the period character do in the middle of each piece of the string?

For example,

```
"blabla" . "blabla" . "blablalba";
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This operator is used to combine strings.

**EDIT**

Well, to be more specific if a value is not a string, it has to be converted to one. See [Converting to a string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) for a bit more detail.

Unfortunately it's sometimes mis-used to the point that things become harder to read. Here are okay uses:

```
echo "This is the result of the function: " . myfunction();
```

Here we're combining the output of a function. This is okay because we don't have a way to do this using the standard inline string syntax. A few ways to improperly use this:

```
echo "The result is: " . $result;
```

Here, you have a variable called `$result` which we can inline in the string instead:

```
echo "The result is: $result";
```

Another hard to catch mis-use is this:

```
echo "The results are: " . $myarray['myvalue'] . " and " . $class->property;
```

This is a bit tricky if you don't know about the `{}` escape sequence for inlining variables:

```
echo "The results are: {$myarray['myvalue']} and {$class->property}";
```

About the example cited:

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

This is a bit tricker, because if we don't use the concatenation operator, we might send out a newline by accident, so this forces lines to end in "\r\n" instead. I would consider this a more unusual case due to restrictions of email headers.

Remember, these concatenation operators break out of the string, making things a bit harder to read, so only use them when necessary.

Comment: `$myarray['myvalue']` and `$class->property` can actually be inlined without `{}`: `"The results are: $myarray[myvalue] and $class->property"`, but this can be a matter of taste/ambiguity/possibility for errors. If you're doing this a lot though (I mean, ***a lot***), concatenation may be better because it's faster.

Comment: Thanks for the throughout explanation!

Answer (score 6):

It's the concatenation operator. It joins two strings together. For example:

```
$str = "aaa" . "bbb"; // evaluates to "aaabbb"
$str = $str . $str;   // now it's "aaabbbaaabbb"
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), concatenating both strings together (making one string out of two separate strings).