# Why are there periods in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, quote

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [What does the 'period' character (.) mean if used in the middle of a php string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104449/what-does-the-period-character-mean-if-used-in-the-middle-of-a-php-string)

Why are the periods included in the code that follows?

```
require("mod/" . $modarrayout . "/bar.php");
```

Obviously, it's because the variable is between strings, but shouldn't the quotes have taken care of that?
PHP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PHP, the period is the concatenation operator.  Putting the periods in tells PHP to concatenate `"mod/"` to `$modarrayout` and then concatenate the resulting string to `"/bar.php"`. See page *[String Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)*.

Answer (score 2):

The following is the same in this case:

```
require("mod/$modarrayout/bar.php");
```

Using [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) is a different approach to string building.

I suggest reading [the manual page on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: String building? [String "interpolation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation#PHP)?

Answer (score 1):

There are two string operators. The first is the concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments. The second is the concatenating assignment operator ('.='), which appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the left side.

Read: *[String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)*