# Converting from a SQL Syntax to MongoDb Syntax Issues

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I have been doing my Homework regarding mongodb and PHP and honestly, I'm fairly new at this and this is my first post at SO.

What does"." operator do in PHP?

*For example*

```
  $cmd = "SELECT m_time,m_latency,m_length FROM pkt_tbl WHERE m_in_port=". $in_port
```

What does "." in .$in_port mean? How can I convert the entire syntax to *mongodb*?

This is my try:

```
$db->pkt_tbl->find(array("m_in_port=".$inport,array("m_time"=>1,"m_latency"=>1,"m_length"=>1));
```

Please correct my syntax and enlighten me regarding "." operator, I badly want to learn and I'm a newbie at PHP and mongodb.

Comment: it's just the strings concatenation operator

Comment: wow. it's really a warm welcome isn't it. I have done as much homework as I can and I get a "-1"rating on my post. Well done guys!

Comment: @Ziumin: Yes, Indeed.I thought so but I just wanted to see if I can directly use that in Mongodb syntax just like how I did it or do i have do something else. Could you please look at my syntax and judge If I did right?

Comment: If you do a google search for 'php period', you get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159172/why-are-there-periods-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is incorrect PHP. Try:

```
$db->pkt_tbl->find(
    array("m_in_port"=>$inport),
    array("m_time"=>1,"m_latency"=>1,"m_length"=>1)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, It's appreciated. However, What does it mean when we say "m_time" => 1  (When it's not mentioned anything in the original syntax, why do we equate it to one)? I'm sorry, I'm a total newbie and I am just trying to learn mongodb.

Comment: @ironman Going through the tutorial will help here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php , however, when you state 1 or 0 in the list of fields in the projection (the second array) 1 states to include the field while 0 states not to.

Comment: wow, thank you so much! It's been a great help guys!

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I have learn't a lot from this thread(That's the purpose of this forum and I'm lovin it!)

Another query that I have tried, Critique Please. 

Sql Statement:
   `$cmd = "SELECT m_out_port FROM pkt_tbl WHERE m_time>=" . $selPointX . "      ORDER BY m_time LIMIT 1";` 

Mongod Statement:
   `$find_query = $db->pkt_tbl->find(
array('m_time'=>$selPointX),
array('m_out_port'=>1),
sort(array('m_time'=>1)->limit(1));`

Please validate.

Comment: @ironman You want to use http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/gte/ on `m_time`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, `.` is the *concatenation* operator. It tells the interpreter to stick strings or variables together end-to-end. For example, `"hello " . "world"` is equivalent to `"hello world"`. In the case of your example, if `$in_port=10`, then your line of code would be equivalent to `"SELECT m_time,m_latency,m_length FROM pkt_tbl WHERE m_in_port=10";`

Comment: wow, couldn't have been any better. Thank you.

What does it mean when we say "m_time" => 1 (When it's not mentioned anything in the original syntax, why do we equate it to one?